# How to extract conversational utterances from single string

Tags: r, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a conversation between several speakers recorded as a single string:

```
convers <- "Peter: hiya Mary: hi how wz your weekend Peter: ahh still got a headache An you party a lot Mary: nuh you know my kid s sick n stuff Peter: yeah i know thats erm al hamshi: hey guys how s it goin Peter: Great Mary: where ve you been last week al hamshi: ah you know camping with my girl friend"
```

I also have a vector of the speakers' names:

```
speakers <- c("Peter", "Mary", "al hamshi")
```

Using this vector as a component of my regex pattern I'm doing relatively well with this extraction:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(convers, 
                paste("(?<=: )[\\w\\s]+(?= ", paste0(".*\\b(", paste(speakers, collapse = "|"), ")\\b.*"), ")", sep = ""))
[[1]]
[1] "hiya"                                        "hi how wz your weekend"                      "ahh still got a headache An you party a lot"
[4] "nuh you know my kid s sick n stuff"          "yeah i know thats erm al"                    "hey guys how s it goin"                     
[7] "Great"                                       "where ve you been last week"
```

However, the first part of the the third speaker's name (`al`) is contained in one of the extracted utterances (`yeah i know thats erm al`) and the last utterance by speaker `al hamshi` (`ah you know camping with my girl friend`) is missing from the output. How can the regex be improved so that all utterances get matched and extracted correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A correct splitting approach would look like

```r
p2 <- paste0("\\s*\\b(?:", paste(speakers, collapse = "|"), ")(?=:)")
strsplit(sub("^\\W+", "", gsub(p2, "", convers, perl=TRUE)), "\\s*:\\s*")[[1]]
# => [1] "hiya"                                       
# => [2] "hi how wz your weekend"                     
# => [3] "ahh still got a headache An you party a lot"
# => [4] "nuh you know my kid s sick n stuff"         
# => [5] "yeah i know thats erm"                      
# => [6] "hey guys how s it goin"                     
# => [7] "Great"                                      
# => [8] "where ve you been last week"                
# => [9] "ah you know camping with my girl friend"
```

The regex to remove speakers from the string will look like

```r
\s*\b(?:Peter|Mary|al hamshi)(?=:)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/N4TTFA/1). It will match

- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?:Peter|Mary|al hamshi)` - one of the speaker names
- `(?=:)` - that must be followed with a `:` char.

Then, the non-word chars at the start are removed with the `sub("^\\W+", "", ...)` call, and then the whole string is split with `\s*:\s*`  regex that matches a `:` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces.

**Alternatively**, you can use

```r
(?<=(?:Peter|Mary|al hamshi):\s).*?(?=\s*(?:Peter|Mary|al hamshi):|\z)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IWCl4f/2). **Details**:

- `(?<=(?:Peter|Mary|al hamshi):\s)` - a location immediately preceded with any speaker name and a whitespace
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars (other than line break chars, use `(?s)` at the pattern start to make it match any chars) as few as possible
- `(?=\s*(?:Peter|Mary|al hamshi):|\z)` - a location immediately followed with 0+ whitespaces, then any speaker name and a `:` or end of string.

In R, you can use

```r
library(stringr)
speakers <- c("Peter", "Mary", "al hamshi")
convers <- "Peter: hiya Mary: hi how wz your weekend Peter: ahh still got a headache An you party a lot Mary: nuh you know my kid s sick n stuff Peter: yeah i know thats erm al hamshi: hey guys how s it goin Peter: Great Mary: where ve you been last week al hamshi: ah you know camping with my girl friend"
p = paste0("(?<=(?:",paste(speakers, collapse="|"),"):\\s).*?(?=\\s*(?:", paste(speakers, collapse="|"),"):|\\z)")
str_extract_all(convers, p)
# => [[1]]
# => [1] "hiya"                                       
# => [2] "hi how wz your weekend"                     
# => [3] "ahh still got a headache An you party a lot"
# => [4] "nuh you know my kid s sick n stuff"         
# => [5] "yeah i know thats erm"                      
# => [6] "hey guys how s it goin"                     
# => [7] "Great"                                      
# => [8] "where ve you been last week"                
# => [9] "ah you know camping with my girl friend"
```

Comment: `ah you know camping with my girl friend` is still missing from the output

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann Sorry, forgot to add the `|\z` alternative. Now, it will work with your input.

Comment: Thanks, great stuff. I've adapted my pattern so it works too (`paste("(?<=: )[\\w\\s]+(?= ", paste0("\\b(", paste(speakers, collapse = "|"), ")\\b|\\z"), ")", sep = "")`by including `\\z`. I guess `\\z`is a character class. What's precisely its meaning/use?

Comment: Okay, got it: `\z` is, largely, equivalent to `$`, matching end of string, right?

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann They are not equal, but you may use `$` here, too. `\z` always matches the very end of string.

Answer (score 5):

What if you take another approach?

Remove all `speakers` from the text and split the string on `'\\s*:\\s*'`

```
strsplit(gsub(paste(speakers, collapse = "|"), '', convers), '\\s*:\\s*')[[1]]

# [1] ""                                            "hiya"                                       
# [3] "hi how wz your weekend"                      "ahh still got a headache An you party a lot"
# [5] "nuh you know my kid s sick n stuff"          "yeah i know thats erm"                      
# [7] "hey guys how s it goin"                      "Great"                                      
# [9] "where ve you been last week"                 "ah you know camping with my girl friend"
```

You can clean up the output a bit to remove the first empty value from it.

Comment: There are two points to note here: 1) if a speaker's name appears inside an utterance, it will get removed, be it a part of a longer string or just a name as is. I believe the speaker's name should only be matched when it is followed with a `:`. 2) The first empty item may not be welcome, at least it is not in the expected results.